# SQL - Grouping a 3 Column List Issue

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

[image]

I have list of values in a databse. There are many redundancies and I want to get rid of them. As you can see in the list below, dates [10/1/2011 - 7/1/2011) have a value of 0. I can make that into one entry with a start date of 10/1/2011 and an end date of 6/1/2011 and a value of 0 and delete all the other rows. I can do that for all the other similar values as well.

Here is my problem. I did this by writing a query that groups these together and then takes the Min(start date) as the start date and the Max(end date) as the end date. Notice that I have two groups of 0 though. When I group this in the query, the start date is 10/1/2010 and the end date is 2/1/2013. This is a problem elsewhere in my code because whenever it looks for a value at 2/1/2012 it finds 0 but it should be finding .955186.

Any suggestions on how I can write a query to account for this problem?

Comment: Add tag of DBMS you use

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you have made.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gaps-and-islands" problem.

If I assume that the first column is sufficient for defining the groups, then you can use a difference of `row_number()`s:

```
select min(startdate), max(enddate), value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by startdate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by value order by startdate) as seqnum_v
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum - seqnum_v), value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a gap and islands problem. You may use the following query (using SQL Server syntax, however, it can be easily altered).

```
select min(startdate) startDate, max(enddate) endDate, value
from
(
  select *, 
         row_number() over (partition by value order by startDate) - (year(startDate) * 12) - month(startDate) grp
  from data
) t
group by value, grp
order by startDate
```

It is using just one `row_number()` which may be better than two since the DBMS does not have to pass the table twice to generate the sequences.